# Create Yosemite install disk on a Windows machine

Tags: macos

I have a 2009 Mac with a new blank SSD. I have a Snow Leopard install disk but it doesn't work (it was a replacement installer disk and has never worked), so I don't have a working OS X install.

I *do* have a Windows 7 machine.

**How should I go about installing Yosemite?** All instructions I can find require OS X at some point in the process. I can't even download it from the store unless I'm on a mac.

Comment: Since the Software is free, it is free only to verified Mac user (you have to have a Mac). So what would you do with Yosemite on a Windows machine?

Comment: I don't want to put Yosemite on a windows machine, I just want OSX on my macbook but I can't do that without first installing OSX on my macbook but I can't do that without first installing OSX on my macbook but I can't do that without first installing OSX on my macbook but I can't do that without first installing...etc.

Comment: Have you tried Internet Recovery, by holding down Command+Option+R at startup until you see a spinning globe in the center of the screen, and let the system start up the recovery partition ??

Comment: It's a totally blank SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without access to an OSX machine. If you have the old disk from your Mac it might have the recovery partition on it. If you can put it back in, boot while holding down command-R. You can put the SSD in an external enclosure and use the recovery partition to install Yosemite on to it.

Maybe if you go to an Apple Store and ask nicely they will let you install Yosemite onto the SSD? Or at least get the installer onto a USB stick.